# Click Class Button Having Same Classname With Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vb.net, dom

I have this code on my webform

```
<div id="q3" class="qdiv">

<span class="number">Question 3 of 3 </span>

<span class="question">About how many times<br>

do you use facebook per week? </span>

<div class="ansbtns" onclick="javascript:change();">

&lt;3

</div>

<div class="ansbtns" onclick="javascript:change();">

4-7

</div>

<div class="ansbtns" onclick="javascript:change();">

7-10

</div>

<div class="ansbtns" onclick="javascript:change();">

10+

</div>
```

These are four buttons I do not want to click first button which have innerhtml > "<3" but want to click any one from which have inner html "4-7" "7-10" and 
"10+"  All of them have class "ansbtns" so how do i click a specific one for example the the one which have "7-10" inner html

i try to use this but this does not click a single of the buttons

```
WebView1.EvalScript("document.getElementsByClassName('ansbtns')[0].click();")
```

Webview1 is EO webbrowser control web control which execute Javascript using
Webview1.evalScript function.ofcourse i am doing this in VB.NET Visual studio

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: `getElementByClassName` returns an array of nodes. your code explicitly picks first element of class `ansbtns` and it is node with `<3` inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try to use `:contains` for this:

```
WebView1.EvalScript("$('.ansbtns:contains(\"4-7\")').click();");
```